# Check if password is correct jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, authentication, passwords

I have problem with a log in form. When I try to log in the javascript always returns the false value even when I am typing correct username and password.

Here is my code in the jQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var teamname = $("#teamname");
var teampassword = $("#teampassword");

function isPasswordCorrect()
{
    var password = teampassword.val();
    var name = teamname.val();
    var result = false;

    $.post('../php/validations/validatePassword.php', {tname: name, tpassword: password}, function(data){
        if(data == 1){
            result = true;
        }else{
            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

$("#join").click(function(){
    if(isPasswordCorrect()){
        alert("You have joined");
    }else{
        alert("You have not joined");
    }
});
});
```

Here is my code in the PHPfile:

```
<?php   
$teamname = $_POST['tname'];
$teampassword = $_POST['tpassword'];

if($teamname != "" || $teampassword !=""){
    include('../connection.php'); // Here is the log in to the phpmyadmin

    $queryCheckPassword = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT password FROM 
    teams WHERE    name = '$teamname'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($queryCheckPassword);
    $teamPassword = $row[0];
    if($teamPassword == $teampassword)
    {
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
}
?>
```

And here is my code in HTML file:

```
<form id="joinform">  <!-- action="teams.php" method="post"> -->
    <ul>
        <div>
            <label>Team name&nbsp<font color='red'>*</font></label>
            <input type='team' name='teamname' id='teamname' placeholder='Team name' readonly='readonly'/>
            <span id='teamnameinfo'>Select an existing team</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="teampassword">Team password&nbsp<font color='red'>*</font></label>
            <input type='password' name='teampassword' id="teampassword" placeholder='Team password'/>
            <span id='teampasswordinfo'>Write team password</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button name='join' id='join'>Join</button> 
        </div>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: **A**JAX is **Asynchronous** - the `result` variable operations are not quite that accurate. Please do the check inside the AJAX callback.

Comment: I hope that code isn't live on the Internet.  If so, you should add some code to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Here is an example [password test using AJAX](http://jayblanchard.net/putting_it_all_together.html)

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thank you for sharing me this useful information. I am going to check that. 
And of course I am not going to put this code on the Internet without SQL injection protection. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PeterKA is correct about the async.  The default value (false) is probably be returning before your async call comes back.  Try adding a callback instead (untested):

```
function isPasswordCorrect(callback)
{
    var password = teampassword.val();
    var name = teamname.val();

    $.post('../php/validations/validatePassword.php', {tname: name, tpassword: password}, 
          function(data) { callback(data == 1); });
}

$("#join").click(function(){
    isPasswordCorrect(function(result) {
        if (result)
           alert("You have joined");
        else
           alert("You have not joined");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your use of Javascript. Look at your `isPasswordCorrect` function (which I have reformatted slightly to make the issue a little clearer):

```
function isPasswordCorrect()
{
    var password = teampassword.val();
    var name = teamname.val();
    var result = false;

    $.post(
        '../php/validations/validatePassword.php',
        {tname: name, tpassword: password},
        function (data) {
            if(data == 1){
                result = true;
            }else{
                result = false;
            }
        }
    );

    return result;
}
```

See that `function (data) {}` in there? That's a callback. The way the `$.post` method works is this:

1. your JS code sends a request to the server using `$.post`
2. your JS code continues, moving on to whatever comes next
3. Some time later (could be 10 milliseconds later, could be 30 seconds later), the server responds to the request. **At that point your callback is called**.

What does this mean? When your code hits the `return result;` line, your code has just submitted the request to the server and the server has probably not responded yet. Thus, `result` is still `false`.

A quick solution to this problem is to move the `alert` statements into the callback, like this:

```
function isPasswordCorrect()
{
    var password = teampassword.val();
    var name = teamname.val();

    $.post(
        '../php/validations/validatePassword.php',
        {tname: name, tpassword: password},
        function (data) {
            if(data == 1){
                alert("You have joined");
            }else{
                alert("You have not joined");
            }
        }
    );
}

$("#join").click(function(){ isPasswordCorrect(); });
```

However, I imagine you're going to want to do more than just `alert` something. You're going to need to research the asynchronous nature of Javascript and understand it before you can extend this fragment to do much.

Answer (score 0):

Because AJAX does not return the result immediately - ASYNCHRONOUS - you want to do the check **only and only when you have the result** - in the AJAX callback like so:

```
function isPasswordCorrect()
{
    var password = teampassword.val();
    var name = teamname.val();
    $.post(
        '../php/validations/validatePassword.php', 
        { tname: name, tpassword: password }, 
        function(data) {
            if(data == 1) {
                alert("You have joined");
            } else {
                alert("You have not joined");
            } 
        }
    );
}

$("#join").click(isPasswordCorrect);
```